# Cancel button not showing in MCBrowserViewController

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I'm working on a simple multipeer application and I'm using the built-in MCBrowserViewController class as follows:

```
 MCBrowserViewController *browserViewController = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc]
                                                                  initWithServiceType:kServiceType
                                                                  session:self.session];
                browserViewController.delegate = self;
                [self presentViewController:browserViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The browser appears fine, but the cancel button doesn't show at the left of the menu bar. If I tap and hold the area where its supposed to be and then drag my finger away so I don't fire the touchUpInside method, the cancel button shows fine.

Anyone else experienced a similar problem (and hopefully solved it)?

Comment: This kind of issues usually happens when you perform UI operations on background thread.

Comment: Brilliant. That's exactly what the problem was. Thanks!